# block <style> from js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, getresponse

this script is a form imported from commercial service . so i don't have possibility to change the code of js.

the problem is every form have css default , so i want import without-block css,

this service  offer a solution  but only with export  html form and not with only js dynamic form

so how block  a css style from output js ?

the code js is a a simple script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.service.com/view_webform.js"></script>
```

and the importer of `<style>` start with this line :

```
  wfso[wid].css = unescape('<style type="text/css">#WFItem html{color:#000;background:#FFF;} #WFItem body..................
```

i can't show full code because There are sensitive data in this file, but for more information the form is provided by getresponse.

the question is still of a general nature, to understand how you can stop the style by js

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to first fetch the JS file via JQuery Ajax. Then read the content as string. Do string operation to find and locate `<style` and `</style>`. Remove the CSS styling code. And once the JS string is free of CSS; then go for `eval`. This JavaScript `eval()` will translate simple JS string into actual JS and all the function present in your JS will be present in your DOM

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://app.service.com/view_webform.js",
  success: (jsData){
  
  var startIndex = jsData.indexOf("<style");
  var endIndex = jsData.indexOf("</style>");
  
  var firstPart = jsData.substr(0, startIndex);
  var endPart = jsData.substr(endIndex+7, jsData.length);
  
  var newJSData = firstPart + endPart;
  
  eval(newJSData);
  }
});
```

Comment: tried but not work, in chrome console after insert your code show this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {", but is not more simple if insert the script in div class and after remove the tag "<style>" in this class div with jquery or javascript  ?, is a good solution ? how make this ?